# CORS issue from local system to VM

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have hosted the application in VM. everything is on VM including UI, database and webservice. When I ran the application on VM it is working, Also when I tried to access the application from local system it is loading the page but it is failing at the time of retrieving data from back end web service.

Back end service is in **.Net Core**

I have already provided cors setting inside the Startup.cs file

**Code**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                             .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                              .AllowAnyHeader()));

        }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you put your code you used for enabling cors.

Comment: @AliK Updated the code

Comment: It seems right I can't find any issues, the one thing I had an issue with in past is only when my webapi was passing some customer header that is non-standard.  Also have you checked fiddler to see the api request and response?

Comment: I checked fiddler, it shows following message
[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. <br />Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). <br />System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:51550

Comment: The error message cited in your comment isn’t a CORS error, and has nothing to do with your CORS configuration. The server is refusing the connection. CORS configuration never causes servers to refuse connections; instead it causes the server to just send back additional response headers.

Comment: @sideshowbarker what  is the solution for this? do we need to configure anything on server/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `AllowAllOrigins` not `AllowAll`.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});
```

and

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1, there is not `AllowAll` as I know